# What happens when you operate bytes bitwise?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Take a look at this code:

```
byte a = -124;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println((a & 0xFF));
```

It outputs:

```
-124
132
```

It's very, very surprising to me. After all, `byte` contains only 8 bits, so that it shouldn't not be changed after `and` with `0xFF`(i.e. `11111111`).

One possible reason is that Java converts `byte` to `int` before doing bitwise operation. Is it the case? If so, why?

Comment: I is so that the `byte` is converted to an `int` because it is defined to be so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Java uses the int primitive type for numbers.

If you want to do bitwise operations on integer primitives of types other than int you can cast the operands explicitly:

```
byte b = -124;
System.out.println("Byte: " + b);
System.out.println("Byte after bitwise and: " + (b & (byte) 0xFF));
```

The code above produces the following output:

> ```
> Byte: -124
> Byte after bitwise and: -124
> ```

Answer (score 2):

0xFF is indeed an int type. So 'a' is promoted to an int prior to the operation.

Comment: This is he wrong reason because also the `byte` in the first output is converted to an `int`.